# Highlight letter when shift and left or arrow pressed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a html element which targets when the right and left arrow are pressed. The default behavior is that when shift is pressed and right arrow key or left are pressed it highlights the next letter only and the previous one is not highlighted, it does not highlight them all to copy the word, how can I highlight all the letters when shift and right or left arrow are pressed at the same time. Thank you.

This is my current code:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller("Ctrl_List", ["$scope", function(scope) {
  scope.keyPress = function(){
     var code = event.which;
      if (code == 37) {
        document.activeElement.selectionEnd--;
          var test = false;
         if(test == false){
        //  document.activeElement.selectionStart--;
          document.activeElement.selectionEnd--;
          if(document.activeElement.selectionStart == 0){
             test = true;
             document.activeElement.selectionEnd = 0;
             document.activeElement.selectionStart = 0;
          }
    }
        if (code == 39) {
            event.preventDefault();
            document.activeElement.selectionStart++;
            //document.activeElement.selectionEnd++;

        }
  }
}]);


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div class="container" ng-controller="Ctrl_List">
  <div class="row">
   <textarea name="text" unselectable="on" id="text" cols="30" rows="10" ng-keydown="keyPress();"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
```

my solution: i think im getting closed.

```
 if (event.shiftKey) {
                //eval("scope." + callFun + "();");
                console.log('shiftKey Pressed');

         if (code == 37) {
              console.log('arrow Pressed');
        }

        if (code == 39) {
              console.log('arrow Pressed');
              document.activeElement.selectionStart == 0;
                 document.activeElement.selectionStart++;
              document.activeElement.selectionEnd++;
        }


            }
```

Comment: What do you want ? `shift+arrow` will highlight letter by letter. This is the default behaviour

Comment: Yes, currently it does not highlight all the lettes, it just highlights one letter when right or left + shift are pressed.

Comment: Thus you need to highlight all the text at once ? Word by word ? Sentence by sentence ?

Comment: i mean when you are copying the word letter by letter using shift + left or right arrow, the same way when you want to a copy a word using shiftkey + right or left arrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question:

> how can I highlight all the letters when shift and right or left arrow are pressed at the same time.

Answer:

```
  if (code == 37 && event.shiftKey) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.activeElement.selectionStart = 0;
    document.activeElement.selectionEnd = document.activeElement.textLength;
  }
```

This will select all the lettters when shift and left arrow keys are pressed.
Working example:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eEmpQM?editors=1011